# What's the result of $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{\sin x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

During a correction of an exercise in a differentiability class this limit showed up and the teacher said that it could be done with L'Hopital easily, but me and a couple of friends tried doing it and neither of us got it. How can it be solved? I know the limit is 0 thanks to Geogebra.

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{\sin x}$$

Comment: You dont need L'Hopital's rule necessarily. It sometimes complicates matters. @Ninad Munshi's answer below shows how easily simple manipulations can provide the limits

Comment: @MarkViola yeah you sure did. But truthfully speaking, had I been a beginner, I would have found your expressions quite scary XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need L'Hospital's Rule.  Rather, using the inequality $e^x >x$ for all $x$ we see that

$$\left|\frac{e^{-1/{x^2}}}{\sin(x)}\right|\le \left|\frac{x^2}{\sin(x)}\right|$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yeah, definitely, that way the limit becomes trivial, thanks for the trick!!

Comment: You're right, I just did it. Sorry, I'm new in this forum!

Comment: Thank you for the opportunity to help!

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the expression as

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}$$

If the limits exist, the limit of the product will be the product of the limits. The limit on the right is $1$. Focusing on the left expression only, use the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x^2}$

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\sqrt{t}e^{-t} = \lim_{t\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{e^t} = 0$$

Comment: Funny how useful that limit is ($\frac{sin(x)}{x}$), I had to use it in an exam today. Thanks for the help!!